# Adapting a Regex to work with MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I've got this Regex that works fine in all my testing, but I am unable to make it work in MySQL, despite the examples that I've been googling and trying variations of this:

`^[A-Za-z]{2,4}-\d{3}-\d{2}$`

In Javascript, it correctly matches `AA-001-01` through `ZZZZ-999-99`, and so have tried it in MySQL with various tweaks to the regex, all with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE sku REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]{2,4}-\d{3}-\d{2}$'
```

*(The table contains thousands of records where `sku` matches the samples given above)*

As best as i can tell, Mysql Regex support is limited, but should this not work properly, or is there some further syntax consideration to work with Mysql?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To match a digit you should use either `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM products
WHERE sku REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]{2,4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$'
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e690b/1).

See the manual for [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Man, my head spins at the mere mention of Regex, and I spend WAY too much time trying to figure it out because when I see it done, I want to slit my throat because it's so DAMN easy......thank you good sir!