# What is the MySQL SQL REGEX for this regex

Tags: java, mysql, regex, squirrel-sql

Regular regex:

```
foo(\((\d{1}|\d{2}|\d{3})\))?
```

This regex works in Java:

```
foo(\\((\\d{1}|\\d{2}|\\d{3})\\))?
```

Examples:

```
fooa      //no match
foo(1)a   //no match
foo(a)    //no match
foo(1)    //match
foo(999)  //match
foo       //match
```

MySQL 5.5 documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) says

```
Note:
Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use 
in your REGEXP strings.
```

I tried as a test running the following on MySQL 5.x

```
select 'foo' REGEXP 'foo(\\((\\d{1}|\\d{2}|\\d{3})\\))?'
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near ''foo(\\([(]\\d{1}' at line 1
```

I looked at [Adapting a Regex to work with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873931/adapting-a-regex-to-work-with-mysql) and tried the suggestion of replacing \d{1} etc.. with [0-9] which gave me:

```
select 'foo' REGEXP 'foo(\\(([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])\\))?'
```

But still getting MySQL death.

Comment: I just copied your SQL syntax and dropped on my MySQL GUI and worked neat. By the way, it returns 1.

Comment: What MySQL version is running on your server?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza hrmm wacked. I was testing it in SQuirreL and it dies there. I dropped it into MySQL Workbench and it works. That's so bizarre. Must be a SQuirreL bug or something. Thanks! haha

Comment: Any way to mark this as complete / answered / not a problem?

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be for you (or someone) to find out exactly why it is failing in SQuirreL and then post that as an answer

Comment: So do you really need it for SQuirreL or for MySQL?

Comment: @CrayonViolent MySQL. I just use SQuirreL for all my testing / queries. The auto-complete is very nice, and I like a lot of the features over MySQL Workbench. Although this bug is disconcerting. If I get some time this week I look into this problem and get back.

Answer (score 1):

Not having an immediately availble MySQL console to verify, this *should* work:

`'foo\\([:digit:]{1,3})\\)?'`

Your other regexes have capture groups around both foo`(123)` and foo(`123`). It doesn't look like you want the capture groups in MySQL (does it even support them?), which would lead to MySQL choking.

Answer (score 1):

Popping in because I ran into this and found the problem/solution.

Go go Global Preferences -> MySQL tab.  Under "Use Custom Query Tokenizer" there is a "Procedure/Function Separator."  If that is "|" change it to something else (like "/").  This is what's causing SQuirreL to fail parsing the REGEX.